# Regular expression to match russian, allow all cyrillic characters in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, cyrillic

How do i redirect url with russian slug to specific php page. For example I have this url.

```
   http://www.example.com/основной-момент.htm
```

and want to redirect to this one in .htaccess

```
   http://www.example.com/category.php?slug=<russian slug>
```

Comment: u can check this link http://code.google.com/p/php-slugs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's allowed in your server you could try something like this for the specific page in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^основной-момент.htm$ category.php?slug=ru
```

In Regex if the character set is enabled on your server you should be able to use the range for the characters:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Яа-я-]+)\.htm$ category.php?slug=ru
```

To capture the phrase you would use this (just like English):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Яа-я-]+)\.htm$ category.php?slug=$1
```

Another way is by detecting the language

```
#For users with Russian as their primary browsing language
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ru [NC]
RewriteRule .* category.php?slug=ru
```

Additionally if you're using a dynamic language on the server you should be able to use the `REQUEST_URI` var for parsing and determining the intended language as Apache serves the content and programming languages (like PHP or Perl) can do more with parsing.