# Cyrillic in htaccess to block Analytics spam

Tags: .htaccess, unicode, utf-8, cyrillic

I have a lot of spam on Google Analytics coming from different domains, and one of them is cyrillic encoded, so I'm in trouble to add it to my `.htaccess` file.

I want to add `с.новым.годом.рф` to the `.htaccess` file to block it, but I don't know how to do that, because the file when saved don't preserve the cyrilic characters.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?с.новым.годом.рф.*$ [NC]
```

is converted to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)??.?????.?????.??.*$ [NC]
```

I have searched a way to convert cyrillic to unicode but I had no success.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: according to another post here in SO, you can do what you say. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978182/reguler-expresson-to-match-russian-allow-all-cyrillic-characters-in-htaccess (type cyrillic characters in htacccess that is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP headers can't include arbitrary raw Unicode characters, so the `Referer` header contains an ASCII [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) rather than Cyrillic characters in an [IRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_resource_identifier).

So you need to use the URI-form in the rule to match. To convert an IRI to a URI you use URL-UTF-8 encoding on path parts, and the [IDN algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) on the hostname.

eg using Python:

```
>>> u'с.новым.годом.рф'.encode('idna')
'xn--q1a.xn--b1aube0e.xn--c1acygb.xn--p1ai'
```

So:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?xn--q1a\.xn--b1aube0e\.xn--c1acygb\.xn--p1ai.*$ [NC]
```

It would still be a good idea to find a text editor for your .htaccess files that doesn't destroy perfectly good Unicode characters though.