# Htaccess for pagination php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am making pagination.
In url i can have language option, category name and page id.
I want to rewrite this url:

> http://test.com/beverages.php?lang=en&category=categoryName&page=1

to this:

> http://test.com/en/beverages/category_name/page/1

But i have 2 options of language

I have tried this, but it is working:

RewriteRule ^(en|ru)/beverages/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([0-9-]+)?$ beverages.php?lang=$1&category=$2&page=$3

Help me please

Comment: You're not permitting underscores (`_`) in your category name (so *category_name* won't match) and you're not taking into account the word *page* in your RegExp

Comment: @CD001 instead of the category_name should be the name

Comment: Rewrite rules usually rewrite the first parameter into the second one. From your requirements you seem to have written them the wrong way around or am I misunderstanding what you want to do?

Comment: I want to rewrite from http://test.com/beverages.php?lang=en&category=categoryName&page=1 to http://test.com/en/beverages/categoryName/page/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues:

**1)** The RegEx itself - the pattern won't match your URL - [try this](https://regex101.com/r/ekmVKf/1):

```
^(en|ru)/beverages/([\w-]+)/page/(\d+)/?$
```

Basically you're not taking into account underscores or the word *"page"* in your pattern.

**2)** You probably want to put the redirect to the document root otherwise the rewrite might take place from your *current* URL, so:

```
/beverages.php?lang=$1&category=$2&page=$3
```

Which should give you the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|ru)/beverages/([\w-]+)/page/(\d+)/?$ /beverages.php?lang=$1&category=$2&page=$3
```

Comment: @rapprogtrainsite - *.htaccess* file is in the document root? The URL in the address bar is something like */en/beverages/gin/page/3*? ... and *beverages.php* is also in the docroot? ... and not spawning any errors.

Comment: on others pages where is just language option all is working but in this page is not working and yes url is: /en/beverages/gin/page/1

Comment: @rapprogtrainsite - had a small error in my RegEx; forgot that in .htaccess you don't want the leading `/` in the pattern, try it now.

Comment: now it is working, but it is not working when i go to url with pages without category, could you help me? Please

Comment: It'll depend on whether the rest of the URL remains the same - to just make the category optional would be simple enough: `^(en|ru)/beverages/(?:([\w-]+)/)?page/(\d+)/?$`

Comment: but why when i go on the page with category and page id is working only if  category with english words, but if with russian it is not working, why?

Comment: @rapprogtrainsite - it's possible that `\w` doesn't match Cyrillic characters in Apache, you might need to be more specific with defining the character set, e.g. `[A-Яа-я-]` [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978182/regular-expression-to-match-russian-allow-all-cyrillic-characters-in-htaccess); I've not actually managed to find out definitively what `\w` actually matches in Apache - or whether it's dependent on a system setting.

Comment: thanks very much, and the last))) help me please with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376578/setup-pagination-with-htaccess

Comment: @rapprogtrainsite - you shouldn't actually need a separate rewrite for that; if it's the same thing but with category optional you can just make category optional in *this* rewrite, e.g. `RewriteRule ^(en|ru)/beverages/(?:([\w-]+)/)?page/(\d+)/?$ /beverages.php?lang=$1&category=$2&page=$3` - *beverages.php* will just receive an empty string for *category* if you leave it out of the URL.