# Setup pagination with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have made pagination, all is working if go in url like this:

> http://test.com/beverages.php?lang=en&page=2

But when i go to the page

> http://test.com/en/beverages/page/2

it is not working. Help me please.

```
RewriteRule ^(en|ru)/beverages?page/(\d+)/?$ /beverages.php?lang=$1&page=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|ru)\\/beverages\\/page\\/(\d+)\\/?$ /beverages.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I fixed regular expression only, you obviously need to add [R=301,L] at the end to make it work in real conditions. Also place it after "RewriteEngine on" and before general redirect rule to index.php and not inside common WP or other CMS block